# How to set up 2D pose with IMU and odometry using robot localization ekf?

Tags: ros2, odometry, imu, robot-localization, ekf-localization

I have a differential drive robot, it is a 4wd robot, 2 motors, 2 encoders,s it behaves like a differential robot actually. Odometry from encoders is working well. I'm using ROS2 Humble on ubuntu 22.04.

I want to fuse odom, with an IMU to get a nice 2d pose (lokalisation)

So, I have done all the transform and got the odom and IMU topics. Which are the followings ODOM topic:

> header: stamp: sec: 1708934625 nanosec: 68893329 frame_id: odom
> child_frame_id: laser_link pose: pose: position: x: 0.9908038973808289
> y: -3.18342661857605  z: 0.0  orientation:  x: 0.0  y: 0.0  z:
> 0.808424464005272  w: 0.5885999371370919 covariance:
>
> 8.632683822477702e-05
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 8.632683822477702e-05
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 8.632683822477702e-05
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 8.632683822477702e-06
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 8.632683822477702e-06
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 8.632683822477702e-06  twist: twist:  linear:  x: 0.05744318664073944  y: -0.010725230909883976  z: 0.0  angular:  x: 0.0  y: -0.0  z:
> 0.046282440423965454  covariance:
> 4.316341911238851e-05
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 4.316341911238851e-05
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 4.316341911238851e-05
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 4.316341911238851e-06
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 4.316341911238851e-06
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 4.316341911238851e-06

AND IMU topic

> header: stamp: sec: 1708934700 nanosec: 58079488  frame_id:
> camera_imu_optical_frame  orientation:  x: -0.564959732796857  y:
> -0.32758730601200314  z: 0.3634408670297931  w: 0.664392800555917  orientation_covariance:
>
> 0.0004
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0004
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0004
>
> angular_velocity:  x: 0.0  y: -0.006981316953897476  z: 0.0
> angular_velocity_covariance:
> 0.01
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.01
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.01  linear_acceleration:  x: 0.22555294632911682  y: -9.728196144104004  z: 1.4808040857315063  linear_acceleration_covariance:
> 1.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 1.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
> 1.0

So Im not sure about the correct EKF yamil config file.

My suggestion was this config

> odom0: /odom/icp
> odom0_config: [true, true, true,  # pose position (x, y, z)
> true, true, true, true,  # pose orientation (quaternion x, y, z, w)
> false, false, false, false, false, false,  # pose covariance
> true, true, false]
>
> ```
> imu0: /imu/data
> imu0_config: [false, false, false,
>               true,  true,  false,
>               false, false, false,
>               false, true, false,
>               true, true, false]
> ```

But not sure if the correct one. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented very well at robot_localiztion [documentation page](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/configuring_robot_localization.html)